# Are there best practices for managing queue and exchange settings and message structure when using RabbitMQ?

Tags: typescript, rabbitmq, microservices

I've been looking for resources on this topic but I've not been able to find anything related. What me and my team have been doing when using RabbitMQ has been to generate classes which carry information as to how to assert queues and exchanges, initiate consumers and ensure that the messages sent to the queue are of a specific structure. Some example code would be:

```js
// rmq.ts
import { Options } from 'amqplib';
import { . . . } from 'class-validator';
import { Topic, Message, ExchangeType } from 'example-rabbitmq';

export class CreatePost extends Topic {
  declare message: CreatePostMessage;
  
  public exchange: string = 'Posts';

  public exchangeType: ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Topic;

  public queue: string = 'Articles_CreatePost';

  public routingKey: string = 'post.create';

  protected queueOptions: Options.AssertQueue = {
    durable: true,
    arguments: {
      'x-message-ttl': 30000,
      'x-dead-letter-exchange': '...',
    },
  };
}

export class CreatePostMessage extends Message {
  @IsUUID()
  public userId: string;

  @IsString()
  @Min(20)
  public title: string;

  @IsString()
  @Max(65000)
  public description: string;

  constructor(userId: string, title: string, description: string) {
    super();

    this.userId = userId;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
  }
}

export class PostCreated extends Topic {
  declare message: PostCreatedMessage;
  
  public exchange: string = 'Posts';

  public exchangeType: ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Topic;

  public queue: string = 'Articles_PostCreated';

  public routingKey: string = 'post.create.success';
}

export class PostCreatedMessage extends Message {
  @IsUUID()
  public id: string;

  constructor(id: string) {
    super();

    this.id = id;
  }
}

// create-post.consumer.ts
import * as postTopics from 'post-topics';
import { RabbitSubscribe } from 'example-rabbitmq';
import PostService from './post.service';

export class CreatePostConsumer {
  constructor(
    private readonly postService: PostService,
    private readonly rabbitMQ: RabbitMQ,
  ) {}

  @RabbitSubscribe(new postTopics.CreatePost())
  public async createPost(msg: postTopics.CreatePostMessage): Promise<void> {
    const newPost = await this.postService.createPost(msg.userId, msg.title, msg.description);

    await this.rabbitMQ.sendMessage(
      new postTopics.PostCreated(),
      new postTopics.PostCreatedMessage(newPost.id),
    );
  }
}
```

The code above is displays the setup of 2 classes where one is designed for receiving events which prompt the creation of a new post, the other one is for sending out an event which informs that the post has been created. This way we've been able to setup classes which would carry the settings which are required for setting up the queue correctly. With this dependency which we've made we're able to setup dead letter consumers easily, can validate that the structure of the message is appropriate for the consumer to work with, if the message has an invalid structure it is returned to the queue once with the hope that the message be picked up by another consumer which would be able to consume the message structure, but if the message is rejected a second time it is sent to the dead letter exchange.

This approach has been successful for the most part but it is progressively becoming difficult to manage all the classes, and we've had to implement migration logic which would update the queue if its setting have been changed.

My primary concern is that we've recreated the idea of gRPC and have brought a lot of unnecessary complexity into the mix.

Is this a common practice to do when working with RabbitMQ? Was there a simpler way of using RabbitMQ which could have saved up a lot of time and energy which would have practically had the same effect?